# AWS Amplify: How to resend MFA code when user does not receive code initially?

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Just like we can resend Signup confirmation code using `Amplify.Auth.resendSignUpCode()`, is there any way to resend MFA code if due to network or any other issues a user does not receive code in the initial Sign-in flow?

I have found a workaround by calling `Auth.signIn()` again, but that would require temporarily storing or passing username and password info across different views, which isn't something I want to do.

Comment: Hey, did you find a resolution to this? I am facing kind of a similar issue and need help.

Comment: Can you just call `Auth.signIn(...)` again?